# CraftyJS w: and h: attributes don't work on images?

Tags: craftyjs

I'm using the craftyjs library and tried to use this function to spawn a pixel image and scale it up:

```
Crafty.e("2D, DOM, Image")
    .attr({x: 0, y: 0, w: 400, h: 400})
    .image("assets/test.png");
```

However it seems to be staying at its original size.. how can I scale it up programmatically?

Answer (score 1):

You should set width and height attributes after the `image` call as it sets them by default to image's width and height.

```
Crafty.e("2D, DOM, Image")
  .image("assets/test.png")
  .attr({w: 400, h: 400});
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me actually.. that would make sense though